# Method orderBy does not exist on view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting error

> method orderBy does not exist on my view.

This is my view:

```
@foreach($post->comments->orderBy('created_at', 'desc') as $comment)
    {{ $comment->comments }}
@endforeach
@stop
```

This is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new post;

    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->save();

    return redirect()->route('rules');
}

public function show($title)
{
    $post = post::where('title', $title)->first();

    return view('post.show', compact('post'));
}


public function storecomment(request $request)
{
    $comment = new comment;

    $comment->post_id = Crypt::decrypt(Input::get('post_id'));
    $comment->comments = $request->comments;
    $comment->save();

    return redirect()->route('rules');
}
```

still getting an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `orderBy()` in a `Collection` object, not in a query.

To make this work exactly as you are doing, you have to do:

```
@foreach($post->comments()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get() as $comment)
   {{ $comment->comments }}
@endforeach
```

But, this way is not the best way to do it.

To make the code clear, you should add this to `comments()` method or create another method that orders the query inside the model.